# SwiftUI List: inserting item + changing section order = app crash

Tags: list, swiftui, crash

Please see the code below. Pressing the button once (or twice at most) is almost certain to crash the app. The app shows a list containing two sections, each of which have four items. When button is pressed, it inserts a new item into each section and also changes the section order.

I have just submitted FB9952691 to Apple. But I wonder if anyone on SO happens to know 1) Does UIKit has the same issue? I'm just curious (the last time I used UIkit was two years ago). 2) Is it possible to work around the issue in SwiftUI? Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

let groupNames = (1...2).map { "\($0)" }
let groupNumber = groupNames.count

let itemValues = (1...4)
let itemNumber = itemValues.count

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var value: Int
    var id = UUID()
}

struct Group: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var id = UUID()
    
    // insert a random item to the group
    mutating func insertItem() {
        let index = (0...itemNumber).randomElement()!
        items.insert(Item(value: 100), at: index)
    }
}

struct Data {
    var groups: [Group]

    // initial data: 2 sections, each having 4 items.
    init() {
        groups = groupNames.map { name in
            let items = itemValues.map{ Item(value: $0) }
            return Group(name: name, items: items)
        }
    }
    
    // multiple changes: 1) reverse group order 2) insert a random item to each group
    mutating func change() {
        groups.reverse()
        for index in groups.indices {
            groups[index].insertItem()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(data.groups) { group in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(group.items) { item in
                            Text("\(group.name): \(item.value)")
                        }
                    }
                header: {
                        Text("Section \(group.name)")
                    }
                }
            }
            Button("Press to crash the app!") {
                withAnimation {
                    data.change()
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

More information:

1. The error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal inconsistency: encountered out of bounds global row index while preparing batch updates (oldRow=8, oldGlobalRowCount=8)'

2. The issue isn't caused by animation. Removing `withAnimation` still has the same issue. I believe the issue is caused by the section order change (though it works fine occasionally).

**Update:** Thank @Yrb for pointing out an out-of-index bug in `insertItem()`. That function is a setup utility in the example code and is irrelevant to the issue with `change()`. So please ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
// multiple changes: 1) reverse group order 2) insert a random item to each group
mutating func change() {
    groups.reverse()
    for index in groups.indices {
        groups[index].insertItem()
    }
}
```

You are attempting to do too much to the array at once, so in the middle of reversing the order, the array counts are suddenly off, and the List (and it's underlying `UITableView`) can't handle it. So, you can either reverse the rows, or add an item to the rows, but not both at the same time.

As a bonus, this will be your next crash:

```
// insert a random item to the group
mutating func insertItem() {
    let index = (0...itemNumber).randomElement()!
    items.insert(Item(value: 100), at: index)
}
```

though it is not causing the above as I fixed this first. You have set a fixed `Int` for `itemNumber` which is the count of the items in the first place. Arrays are 0 indexed, which means the initial array indices will be (0...3). This line `let index = (0...itemNumber).randomElement()!` gives you an index that is in the range of (0...4), so you have a 20% chance of crashing your app each time this runs. In this sort of situation, always use an index of (0..<Array.count) and make sure the array is not empty.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb for your answer. I doubt it a bit though. I think the change made to data model by `change()` is "atomic", in the sense SwiftUI doesn't generate a view hierarchy when `change()` run halfway. Isn't it? If so, how come the intermediate change inside it could be visible to the rendered view hierarchy?

Comment: Regarding the issue with insertItem(), yes, you're right. But that's a mistake in my test code (I modified the code a bit before I posted it and it was introduced at that moment). It's just a setup to reproduce the issue with change(). But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Even if it is atomic, the view has to update one at a time. The two changes break that. The simple test is to remove one or the other. It works fine. As to exactly how it breaks SwiftUI updating, we don't know. That is for the SwiftUI team at Apple. Also, I am not saying this is not a bug, as it could be handled. However, right now your fix is to change 1 at a time.

Comment: Yes, I was aware it worked fine if I just performed one change at a time. But I think doing both together should work too, for two reasons: 1) While it's rare, I did observe the current code worked occasionally 2) In practical apps, it's usually not possible to split the change in two steps. Take my app for example, a list contains all bank acount transactions per day. Each account's transactions are in a section. The sections are ordered by total transaction amount in the account. If user adds a new transaction amount, it may change section order at the same time.

Comment: Then file a bug report. I am not disputing that it is probably a bug.

Comment: But I agree with you this is something that SwiftUI can't support yet. Hmm...it seems I need to consider displaying sections in fixed order. Thanks.

Comment: I submitted FB9952691. Not sure if it's publicly viewable (I'm not familar with those Apple tools).

Comment: They are not. Add it to [OpenRadar](https://openradar.appspot.com/page/1)

Comment: Oh, I thought openradar is obsoleted by FB? I don't even have an account on it. It's late night here. I'll sign up and add it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: OpenRadar just lets others see the bugs you reported. Apple does not use OpenRadar, so you need to use Feedback Assistant to report, but that is not a publicly viewable system. It will be up to you to update the OpenRadar flings with Apple's responses.

Comment: Done. It's at https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9952691 (though I doubt if Apple engineers will response to the case I submitted in Feedback Assistant).

Answer (score 0):

I got Apple's reply regarding FB9952691. The issue has been fixed in iOS16 (I verified it).